# circuits gates in Python

Tags: python

I have downloaded a program made in Python called logic.py from the following source:

http://www.openbookproject.net/courses/python4fun/logic.html

By reading the source code it seems not so hard to understand, but the problem that I got is with the implementation of the XOR gate, I have labeled the figure with the gates I suppose that are correct and the code is below:

[image]

```
class Xor(Gate2):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Gate2.__init__(self, name)
        self.A1 = And("A1")   # See circuit drawing to follow connections
        self.A2 = And("A2")
        self.I1 = Not("I1")
        self.I2 = Not("I2")
        self.O1 = Or("O1")
        self.A.connect([self.A1.A, self.I2.A])
        self.B.connect([self.I1.A, self.A2.A])
        self.I1.B.connect([self.A1.B ])
        self.I2.B.connect([self.A2.B ])
        self.A1.C.connect([self.O1.A ])
        self.A2.C.connect([self.O1.B ])
        self.O1.C.connect([self.C ])
```

The question that I have is what are the following parts doing:

```
self.A.connect([self.A1.A, self.I2.A])     (*)
self.B.connect([self.I1.A, self.A2.A])     (**)
```

because for what I see the output of the NOT gate (I1) connects to the second input of the AND gate (A1), and then the output of the I2 connects to the second input of A2. At the end both outputs of A1 and A2 (which are C) connects as inputs of the OR gate. So what is the purpose of (* and **)? I do not see where they are attached in the circuit.

Any tip?

PD. I have tested the program by using Python 2.5 and 2.7; and in both cases I got an error in the following line:

```
print(int(F3.Cout.value), end='')
```

it is in the test4bit function, so I had to erase it; I said that just in case somebody got the same error.

Update: According to the solutions they gave me, this particular line:

```
self.A.connect([self.A1.A, self.I2.A])
```

I suppose that is getting connected as the input A from the AND gate A1, but where does it says that in the code? That is the part in which I am lost.

Thanks

Comment: I assume the `.A` indicates an input to the gate, in which case one of the inputs to A1 is the same input as I2 (wire A), and one of the inputs to A2 is the same as the input to I1 (wire B).

Comment: The reason you got that error is the `print` function does not exist in python 2, it was added in python 3 as the replacement for the `print` keyword. You should probably use python 3 to run this code.

Answer (score 2):

Both lines are showing a single input that connects to the inputs of two separate gates. For example, this line:

```
self.A.connect([self.A1.A, self.I2.A])
```

Is showing that the overall input `A` is wired to two inputs: input `A` on the AND gate A1 and input `A` on the NOT gate `I2`. That's indicated in the wiring diagram by the red circle/square:

[image: Annotated wiring diagram]

The line `self.B.connect([self.I1.A, self.A2.A])` does the same thing with the `B` input to the XOR gate, wiring it to `I1` and `A2` (the blue circle above).

---

The error you saw with `print` is because it is a function in Python 3. For Python 2.x, you just do `print "Stuff I want printed"`.

Comment: thanks @thegrinner, but how they reconnect those A and B again to the circuit?; I do not see any reference to A and B later on the code. Because the A and B seems not to be called again in the code.

Comment: @Little The code is connecting both pins at once by passing the input in as a list - so if you only wanted input B to go to the NOT gate, you would have `self.B.connect([self.I1.A])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can add to @thegrinner answer that all two-input element has inputs named: "A" and "B". And one input element has input named "A". Also your circuit has external inputs "A" and "B" and output pin named "C".
So at the line `self.B.connect([self.I1.A, self.A2.A])` you connect external input pins of the XOR gate to the pins "A" of the internal gate I1 (invertor) and A2 (logical-and, also to the input pin "A").